# Random 'GUID' and Possible Duplicates

Tags: random, collision

(I am using 'guid' as a term for a random series of letters/numbers.)

I am using a function to create a GUID that will be unique. The function is:

```
function guid() {
    return sprintf('%04X%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%04X%04X',
                  mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535),
                  mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(16384, 20479),
                  mt_rand(32768, 49151), mt_rand(0, 65535),
                  mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535));
  }
```

This returns a value like 'A881264F-AB87-4592-BFC1-714AFFDEE698'. The function is used to assign a (hopefully) unique filename to an uploaded picture. (The actual image file name is stored along with the GUID value in a row in the table.) The intent is that each picture's file name will be unique.

This has worked well in this application for several years. Lately I've been getting what I think are duplicate file names, so that a record doesn't point to the original picture filename, but a newer picture that randomly got (re-used) an existing filename.

I am aware that I may need to add additional characters to the filename, like a date/timestamp, so that I can ensure that the filename is (and always will be) unique.

My question is related to the 'chances' of there being a duplicate GUID generated over a long period of time.

Assuming that the GUID is created as the function above, and results are like 'A881264F-AB87-4592-BFC1-714AFFDEE698', what are the chances (maybe not the right term) that the function might come up with the same result?

Note that this is not about 'how many' different results there will be, but what are the chances that the function will return the same result?

Answer (score 0):

The basic rule of thumb is the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). It says that in a crowd, there is ~50% probability that there is a collision, if there are sqrt(N) elements in the crowd, where N is the possible values (it is an approximation).

This GUID has 122-bit state. So after 2^61 generated elements, you'll get a collision with about 50% probability.

Looking at the linked wikipedia page, you'll get a collision after generating ~10^10 elements with a ~10^-17 probability (that's an approximation of mine, using the approximation formula, but the order of magnitude is the important here).

Maybe you want to stop using GUIDs, and use a more compact way of encoding random state, so in the same length filename, you can put more state, lowering the chance of collisions.

Answer (score 0):

geza's answer is technically correct, but I think it draws wrong conclusions and misses the context of `mt_rand`. GUIDs with 122-bit state are random enough that you can expect never to run into collisions while doing something simple like naming pictures. There are not enough pictures in the world to even think about collisions in this case. 2^61 is a ridiculously high number. So I wouldn't recommend going out of your way to get a longer state.

Now, the context of `mt_rand` matters:

1. You may run into duplicates if you use `mt_srand` to set the seed in a not properly random way.
2. If the random identifier is not supposed to be guessed by the user, you shouldn't use `mt_rand` at all. Even though it's got a long period, it's easily predictable. (See this for example: http://www.openwall.com/lists/john-users/2012/09/20/2) If the user can influence the name at all, it could be done on purpose to cause conflicts.

Comment: If you have 2^61 pictures, then you'll have ~50% probability of collision. Of course, you don't want this. 50% is way to high if you want to avoid collisions. That's why I used 10^-17 probability. It is low enough to be acceptable. With this probability, you can have 10^10 pictures. Yeah, this number seems to be large enough. But it doesn't have too much safety margin. Adding a little bit more entropy to the filename doesn't hurt, I think. I'm not saying that it must be done, but the solution will be more collision free, and it takes literally nothing. Except if using GUIDs are a must.

Comment: I simply don't feel good when 128-bit (or less) hashes used when collision free is a requirement. Plus, you cannot be absolutely sure about the quality of the random generator. Even mersenne twister has flaws.

Comment: @geza I'm making an assumption here that the poster does not have 2^61 pictures (or anything in those orders of magnitude) or they wouldn't ask the question here. For some comparison that's 300M photos of every person on the planet. That would mean exabytes of storage. (assuming really tiny pictures)